# How do I get Laravel to listen to private Pusher channels?

Tags: private, laravel-5.4, pusher, broadcasting, laravel-echo

I read a few other questions similar to this but wasn't able to find a satisfactory answer, so just asking again with what I have done in my code so far.

in resources/assets/bootstrap.js I have

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '8c5cc1d9fe77464ac2df',
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true,
    authEndpoint: '/chat4/public/authenticate-broadcasting',
});
```

and in my routes/web.php I have:

```
Route::post('/authenticate-broadcasting', function () {
  return true;
});
```

but when I load the application page, in console I get:

```
POST http://laraveldemo-one.com/chat4/public/authenticate-broadcasting 500 (Internal Server Error)

Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 500
```

I installed Laravel Echo and Pusher correctly because if I use public channels, my application works perfectly, but I'm failing miserably using private channels, I'm not sure what else I can try as I have read thru the documentation a few times and can't find anything I'm missing. Help me please! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must send csrf_token
You can send via meta tags or in Echo json parameter with 
auth: {
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': 'some_csrf_token'
    }
  }

https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect